# WordPress child theme for admin only (development)

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I'd like to restrict a child theme to only being visible to me, the admin, for development purposes. Then I can make changes, upload and view them live and on the site without other people seeing those unfinished changes. Once I'm done, I take the affected files and move them to the Parent Theme's folder to make the changes visible to everyone.

Is this possible with some kind of script through functions.php?

And I'm not just talking about enqueuing the style.css file, I'm talking about setting up a complete child theme with sidebar.php, header.php etc. and only have the child theme files being loaded for me, the admin, for development purposes. Perhaps a way to define the child theme directory, embedded inside a condition that checks whether the user is admin.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that does what you are looking for called [Theme Test Drive](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-test-drive/). I haven't used it before but I think it uses some filters to update the theme at runtime for logged-in admin users.

Essentially, you install your new theme and activate it using the plugin instead of the theme switcher in the admin.